# Quiero pasar como parametro la fecha elegida en un datapicker hacia una vista en djanago

Tags: django, datepicker

Por favor ayudenme a pasar como parametro una fecha elegida en un datepicker, para que atraves de la url sea recibida en una vista.

mi objetivo es actualizar información de esa fecha elegida dentro de cards que tengo en un template. Estoy utilizando django.

**En el template:**

```
    <div>
     <label for="Resultados">Resultados del dia:</label>
     <input type="date" id="globalDate" name="date"  min="2020-01-01">
    <script>
      document.getElementById('globalDate').value = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
    </script>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center">
    <tbody>                      
    {% for sorteo in sorteos %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{sorteo.fecha_sorteo|date:"d-m-Y"}}</td>
    <td><span class="balls">{{sorteo.primera}}</span>&nbsp;<span class="balls"> 
    {{sorteo.segunda}}</span>&nbsp;<span class="balls">{{sorteo.tercera}}</span></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
     </div>

    </div>
```

**url:**

```
    urlpatterns = [

       path('', views.home, name='Home'),
       path('sorteos/<fecha>', views.sorteos, name='Sorteos')
    ]
```

**view:**

```
    def sorteos(request, fecha):

       sorteos=Sorteos.objects.filter(fecha_sorteo__exact=fecha)

     return render(request,'Website/sorteos.html',{'sorteos':sorteos})
```